# Python library for handling and limiting bandwidth of all processes in Windows 10

Tags: library, python, data, internet, bandwidth

I am using [`netlimiter`](https://www.netlimiter.com/), a bandwidth controlling system, in which we can limit bandwidth to a given value, kill connections and monitor realtime data usage by all processes.
But It has limited trial period.

I am looking for either a library or any way to limit (to a specified data speed) and monitor realtime data usage using python.
Suggestions are appreciated.

I have `python 3.8.5` and working on `Visual Studio Code`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-your-data-limit-031dcc15-fa0f-ad39-8e60-634500585630#WindowsVersion=Windows_10) handles limiting bandwidth natively. You can go to **Data usage** in **Settings** and adjust the bandwidth

[image]

Comment: I want to do this by my gui. How to do this using code?

Comment: This doesn't limit the usage of particular program, but limits usage by all programs.

Comment: This limits total overall data used for a period of time. It is not a bandwidth controlling system in the sense that is being asked.